# TypeError: Object of type RelativeBy is not JSON serializable error using Selenium 4's Relative Locator with Python 3

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium4, relative-locators

I am running Python 3.7.1 and ***Selenium 4.0.0a6***.  I want to use the new Relative Locator functions in Selenium 4 but always get a:

```
TypeError: Object of type RelativeBy is not JSON serializable
```

error.

More specifically, I first call:

```
the_name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//h3[contains(text(),'New_6')]")
```

(without the enclosing double-quotes). I know I have successfully acquired the element, because when I do a:

```
print(the_name.text)
```

I get back ***New_6***

I then call:

```
dotz = driver.find_element(with_tag_name("XPATH").to_right_of(the_name))
```

(the element I'm looking for is to the right of the_name). Unfortunately, I get the `not JSON serializable` message.

The page I'm working on looks like this:

```
<h3 class="renameable" contenteditable="false" style="" xpath="1">New_6</h3>
<span class="icon icon-threedots action dijitDownArrowButton" role="img" aria-label="more options" tabindex="-1" id="dijit__HasDropDown_7" widgetid="dijit__HasDropDown_7" popupactive="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="dijit_TooltipDialog_12" xpath="1"></span>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

(As of 05/20/2021, with Selenium 4.0 still in beta (i.e. via `pip install selenium==4.0.0.b3`))

According to https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/selenium-with-python/, the singular `find_element()` doesn't handle RelativeBy requests. You have to use instead the plural `find_elements()`. Quote:

> Issue with using find_element method for Relative Locators

> In relative locators in Selenium 4 for Java, the find_element method was used to return the WebElement’ relative’ (i.e., left, right, near, etc.) to the corresponding element. Though the official Selenium documentation for Selenium 4 Python states that the find_element method should also be used in Python for finding relative locators; using the find_element results in the following error:

> TypeError: Object of type RelativeBy is not JSON serializable

> After digging through the implementation of find_element in WebDriver, I realized that no changes were made in the find_element method (in Selenium 4 Python) for returning a relative locator.

> ... we have to use the find_elements method instead of the find_element method for using Relative Locators in Selenium 4 (with Python). Since the find_elements method returns a list of the WebElement(s) that match the given web locator strategy, we need to parse through the list to perform relevant actions on the required ‘relative’ web element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of a couple of things here:

- As of *21<sup>th</sup> August, 2022* as per the current documentation of [***Relative Locators***](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/locators/#relative-locators) the command seems to be a little off and instead of `with_tag_name()` you need:

  ```
  locate_with(By.TAG_NAME, "tag_name")
  ```
- As you are using *`By.TAG_NAME`* you need to pass the exact tagname i.e. **`span`**, effectively:

  ```
  locate_with(By.TAG_NAME, "span")
  ```

---

### Solution

Your effective code block will be:

```
the_name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//h3[contains(text(),'New_6')]")
dotz = driver.find_element(locate_with(By.TAG_NAME, "span").to_right_of(the_name))
```