# TypeError: Object of type RelativeBy is not JSON serializable error using relative_locator through Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium4, relative-locators

I'm trying to write my own flight tracker using selenium and chrome driver. In order to get to the input box, I'm trying to travel down the tree of embedded html elements (for some reason I can't get straight to it, even using the xpath attribute in webdriver).

I tried the solution from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62720390/error-when-using-selenium-4s-relative-locator-with-python-3) but it did not work (currently using a newer version of selenium, so this solution might be outdated)

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.relative_locator import locate_with

driver_service = Service(executable_path = '/path/chromedriver')
url = 'https://www.google.com/travel/flights'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service = driver_service)
browser.get(url)
bigBody = browser.find_element(By.ID,'yDmH0d')
#WebElement data type
wrongWiz = bigBody.find_element(By.ID, 'ow4')
wizLoc = locate_with(By.TAG_NAME, 'c-wiz').below(wrongWiz)
bigWiz = bigBody.find_elements(wizLoc) 
##This part is what throws the error, whether I'm using element or elements.
```

Here's the error:

```
TypeError: Object of type RelativeBy is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to do? You appear to be passing a collection of elements to a locator function which doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are getting that error but there's most likely a better/easier way to find the element you want but it's not clear which element you are looking for. You say an INPUT but never specified which one.

Comment: @JeffC I'm trying to find the destination input box on the Google Flights webpage. In the html, the box doesn't have a name, ID, or any other sort of identifier, so my strategy was to just move through the nested elements until I got to the input box. I'm sure there's an easier approach, but I'm not sure what it would be!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of the code:

```
locate_with(By.TAG_NAME, 'c-wiz')
```

though a legitimate [**Relative Locators**](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/locators/#relative-locators) based expression, but still you have to pass it as an argument to *`browser.find_element()`* as follows:

```
wizLoc = driver.find_element(locate_with(By.TAG_NAME, 'c-wiz').below(wrongWiz))
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved my type error but now I'm getting the error: "Message: invalid argument: 'using' must be a string"

I'm trying to find the destination input box on the Google Flights webpage. The box doesn't have a name, ID, or any other sort of identifier, so my strategy was to just move through the nested elements until I got to the input box. I agree with JeffC, I'm sure there's an easier approach, but I'm not sure what it would be!

Comment: Glad to be able to help you. That's a different issue altogether :) Feel free to raise a new question with your new requirement.